# error 'null' when inserting mail signature iphone

Tags: iphone, email, signature

i made an image on my computer that I want to use as a e-mailsignature (outlook and iphone). 
In outlook it works fine. 
To install on my iphone, I sent the an mail to myself -> copy -> shake iphone -> undo. 
When I open a new mail on my iphone I keep receiving the errror message 'null' where the image should be?

I have been searching for hourse on forum's, but cant find an immediate solution. I always come back on the shake function, which I used.

Any ideas?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a .jpg file. I exported to be a .png and it worked with that for some reason.